# Slick carousel image won't scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Encoutered a problem with Slick carousel that makes images not to scale based on browser size (images original size is 300x228px).

Just to be clear:
When I shrink the browser window, there are less slides but no image resizing.

I've been trying to fix this with no success.
Here's the code I'm currently using.

```js
     $(document).on('ready', function () {
            $(".slideslick").slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  arrows: false,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 880,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
   
        });
```

```css
.slideslick {
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0px auto;
        }
        .slide1 img {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto
        }
        .slide2 img {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto
        }
        .slide3 img {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto
        }
        .slide4 img {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto
        }
        .slide5 img {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto;
        }
        .slick-slide{
          width: 300px
        }
        .slick-slide img{
          max-width: 100%;
          height: auto;
          min-width: 200px;
          min-height: 150px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slideslick">   
        <div class="slidercontent1">
            <div class="slide1">
                <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/incomparablesdelamor.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slidercontent2">
            <div class="slide2">
                <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/sorayamantari.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slidercontent3">
            <div class="slide3">
                <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/nandodelmantaro.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slidercontent4">
            <div class="slide4">
                <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/nandodelmantaro.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slidercontent5">
            <div class="slide5">
                <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/nandodelmantaro.png">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query which makes the width of the image to 100% if the screen is less than 800px

```
@media(max-width:800px) {
  .slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $(".slideslick").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    arrows: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 880,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]
  });

});
```

```css
.slideslick {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.slide1 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.slide2 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.slide3 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.slide4 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.slide5 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  width: 300px
}

.slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

@media(max-width:800px) {
  .slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideslick">
  <div class="slidercontent1">
    <div class="slide1">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slidercontent2">
    <div class="slide2">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slidercontent3">
    <div class="slide3">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slidercontent4">
    <div class="slide4">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slidercontent5">
    <div class="slide5">
      <img draggable="false" src="https://placehold.it/500x200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```